# ASP.NET 5 Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime >= 1.0.0-rc2-16237 could not be resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dnx

I have a ASP.NET 5 solution working on my desktop computer for a while, but today I tried running it on my laptop and I can't get the solution to open, it basically either crashes after initializing or it loads and gives "NU1001 The dependency Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime >= 1.0.0-rc2-16237 could not be resolved

1.0.0-rc2-16237 is installed according to dnvm list:

```
Active Version           Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------------- -----
       1.0.0-beta5       clr     x64          win
       1.0.0-beta5       clr     x86          win
       1.0.0-beta5       coreclr x64          win
       1.0.0-beta5       coreclr x86          win
       1.0.0-rc1-final   clr     x64          win
       1.0.0-rc1-final   clr     x86          win
       1.0.0-rc1-final   coreclr x64          win
       1.0.0-rc1-final   coreclr x86          win
  *    1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x64          win
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86          win             1.0.0-rc2-1635...
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x64          win
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x86          win
       1.0.0-rc2-16357   coreclr x64          win
```

However when I try "dnvm use 1.0.0-rc2-16357" I get "*Cannot find dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc2-16357, do you need to run 'dnvm install 1.0.0-rc2-16357'?*".

When running the install command I get "*There are no runtimes matching the name dnx-clr-win-x86 on feed https://www.nuget.org/api/v2.*"

In my projects I reference DNX 4.6

Comment: Where do u have the version "dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc2-16357" ? The newest is still "1.0.0-rc1-update1"

Comment: RC 2 relies on the dotnet command and you should dig that further. It is still nightly builds, so rush into it is not a good idea.

Comment: thanks, reverted back to rc1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the reference to 1.0.0-rc1 from 1.0.0-rc2-16357 in project.json fixed the problem